# Can't modify Navigation drawer using supportv7

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

I would implement the nav drawer with supportv7 library so i will use the app even with 2.3 Android.. I can't do it.. I follow some example but still have errors.. This is what i have written so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Customizzo la actionbar */
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbarcustom);
        setTitle("Hi");
        int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
            if (title != null) {
                title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Hi All")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("News", R.drawable.news));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Second Tab", R.drawable.arrow));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Third tab", R.drawable.high_importance));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("4 tab", R.drawable.star));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("5 Tab", R.drawable.spam));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("6 Tab", R.drawable.group));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            if (dataList.get(0).isSpinner()
                    & dataList.get(1).getTitle() != null) {
                SelectItem(2);
            } else if (dataList.get(0).getTitle() != null) {
                SelectItem(1);
            } else {
                SelectItem(0);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            break;  
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:      
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, settings.class);
                startActivity(i);           
                return true;
            }   

        return false;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                SelectItem(position);
            }

        }
    }

  }
```

these are the imports:

```
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.*;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.readystatesoftware.systembartint.*;
import java.util.*;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

The errors are in these lines:

```
fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
```

seems that the method is not applicable to android.app.Fragment.. I tried in every way without success.. Is there something else to change?

Comment: You need to use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and not `android.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Fragment` class from support library. `SupportFragmentManager` works with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not with `android.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be extra careful with wild card imports. In your case, importing android.app.* causes the problem since `android.app.Fragment` is part of the package.

You need to make sure you are importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead, to match the arguments of `FragmentTransaction.replace(int, Fragment)`.

Comment: well i imported the supportv7 in all fragments and now i get only one error in `getSupportFragmentManager();`

Comment: `An instance of type android.support.v4.app.Fragmentmanager can not be assigned to a variable of type android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: Then you could try by removing all wild card imports and work from there. But the error message makes no sense, it looks like your IDE is having a hard time following your changes, maybe a relaunch would also help if you're using Eclipse :)

Comment: I'm using AIDE right now because my eclipse doesn't work and i need compile the project. :) Do you think it's only an import problem?

Comment: I don't think you still have an import error, but removing wild cards and checking everything couldn't hurt as they might cause conflicts... It looks like what happens when the project is not refreshed in Eclipse, and the IDE is still trying to flag errors that have been solved. Apart from closing and reopening the IDE to see if it refreshes the error flags, I don't how I could help you further, sorry :/

Comment: Ok thanks :( last thing, is it correct extends ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Yes, you need that use the support library, for example to call getSupportFragmentManager() ...